# Is "take…to" a variant of "hold…to"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I have a question about the possible usage of "*take something to*":

> 1. He **took** a knife **to** her neck.
> 2. He **held** a knife **to** her neck.

Is the "*take... to*" pattern a standard English variant of the "*hold ... to*" pattern?

Comment: Is it took or put? Put/held a knife to her neck are almost interchangeable, but took a knife to her neck is not.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem  It is "***take*** *a knife to her neck*"  that I originally wanted to ask about.

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

To "hold a knife to" something specifically means you are holding the edge of the knife against the object, but not cutting it (yet).

To "take [a tool] to" something is an idiomatic way of saying "use [a tool] on" something. If you're using a knife, you *are* cutting with it. (Because this is a somewhat informal idiom, it has connotations of being casual or even careless with how you use the tool, as TRomano's answer pointed out.)

In short: holding a knife to her neck is a threat of violence; taking a knife to her neck is carrying out the threat.

Answer (score 3):

"Take to" is a phrasal verb with *many* different meanings. The meaning in your example sentence #1 goes like this: "take an *X* to *Y*" means "get an *X* (in your hands), bring it to *Y,* and apply it (using your hands) in the way natural for an *X*." The action referred to in this sense of "take to" is usually destructive or violent. (This is sense 24b of "take" in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/197158), which mentions using a stick to "beat" a person or thing.)

So, your example sentence #1 suggests not that he held a knife to her neck, but that he *cut* her neck, since cutting is the typical use for knives. It's not completely clear that he killed her, because "take to" is somewhat vague, but when you "take a knife to" something, you cut it.

Here are a couple other examples of this sense of "take to":

> Hush or I'll **take** a belt **to** you, you noisy brat! = If you (small child) don't quiet down, I'll get a belt and whip you with it.
>
> It's time to **take** a saw **to** that tree. = That tree is so old, it should be cut down (with a saw).

### But watch out: “take to” is tricky

But be aware that the other meanings of "take to" can sound very similar to this one even though they mean very different things, and the grammatical differences that enable a fluent speaker to tell one sense apart from another are complex and subtle. For example, "Julia took to swimming" means that Julia enjoyed learning to swim and found that she was naturally good at it; "I took Julia to swimming practice" means that I drove Julia in my car (or walked with her, guiding her) to her swimming practice; "Julia took six sessions to master swimming" means that Julia required six sessions to master swimming; "I took Julia to a movie" means that I accompanied Julia to a movie and paid her admission. And there are many more meanings beyond those.

### No connection with “hold to”

None of the above has anything to do with "hold to", which is completely different (and likewise filled with complexity and ambiguity). While there are analogies between all phrasal verbs that use the same preposition, those analogies are subtle and muddy. Swapping "take…to" and "hold…to" won't produce any simple, regular change in meaning.

It's often best to understand English phrases as indivisible grammatical units, not carrying a meaning that results from combining the meanings of the individual words according to word-independent grammatical rules. For example, "hold you to your promise" has a clear, recognizable meaning; "take you to your promise" is meaningless.

Comment: I used to be an adventurer like you, but then I took a knife to the neck.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Thanks for taking one for the team. Seriously, I find myself thinking that there is simply no humanly possible way to learn the phrasal verbs with "get" and "take". And yet natives distinguish them effortlessly.

Answer (score 3):

I would add that in *take to* there is the sense of *roughly or indelicately applying an implement*.

We can *take an ax to a tree* or *take a torch to a seized hex-nut* or *take a sledge hammer to a slab of concrete*.

If someone took a knife to something, it would involve hewing or slashing or hacking.

A surgeon would not "take a scalpel to a patient". The surgeon's use of the implement requires delicacy and precision.

Nor would we *take glue to a model airplane*.  Glue is not an implement. However, someone could *take a glue-gun to a model airplane* in which case the statement would probably have ironic connotations: the glue would not have been neatly or carefully applied.